# MVC - Updating multiple records to database using EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC. I am getting error while updating multiple records to database using EF.

- I want to create a group and add members in it.
- I created to list
  boxes. I have loaded all members in left box.
- First time, I created the Group and added members from first box to second box, and saved
  the form. All data saved successfully.
- While I come to edit the group, I want to add/remove some members from the group, I got
  error.

I used the following code for edit mode.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupView.GroupName) && groupView.MemberIDs.Count > 0) 
{
Groups group = new Groups();
List<GroupMembers> existingMembers = null;
if (groupView.GroupID > 0)
{
       group.GroupID = groupView.GroupID;
   //db.Entry(group).State = EntityState.Modified;
   existingMembers = db.GroupMembers.ToList();
}
else
{
   group.GroupID = groupView.GroupID;
   group.GroupName = groupView.GroupName;
   group.IsActive = true;
   db.Groups.Add(group);
}
    GroupMembers groupMembers, member;
foreach (short memberId in groupView.MemberIDs)
{
   groupMembers = new GroupMembers();
       if (groupView.GroupID > 0)
   {
      //Check whether the Member already exists in the group
      member = existingMembers.Where(gm => gm.GroupID == groupView.GroupID && gm.MemberID == memberId).FirstOrDefault();
      if (member != null)
      {
    groupMembers.GroupMemberID = member.GroupMemberID;
    db.Entry(groupMembers).State = EntityState.Modified;
      }
      else
    groupMembers.GroupMemberID = 0;
   }
   groupMembers.GroupID = group.GroupID;
   groupMembers.MemberID = memberId;
   groupMembers.IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(groupView.IsActive);
   if (groupMembers.GroupMemberID == 0)
       db.GroupMembers.Add(groupMembers);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

At runtime I received the following exception:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key

If I removed the following code from the above coding, duplicate data inserted in DB.

> db.Entry(group).State = EntityState.Modified;

I am new to MVC, EF, as per my knowledge I wrote the above coding. I searched and checked some questions with the error information, but I am not able to understand clearly. So I put my coding. Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is groupid is the primary key?

Comment: Yes, for Groups class. Foreign key in GroupMembers class...